# C++ get greyscale array from .bmp file

Tags: c++, bmp, grayscale

I have to read in a .bmp file as a 2D array of its greyscale values so I can analyze the values of each pixel. I've never done anything with image files so I have no idea where to begin. Can anyone offer a beginner-friendly explanation as to how to do this? All I need is to convert a .bmp file into a 2D array of integers representing that pixel's greyscale value.

Comment: There are two parts to this problem: 1. reading in a BMP file; 2. converting from RGB to greyscale. Both parts have answers here on StackOverflow.

Comment: There are several image libraries available for you to use, including some that will convert from full colour to grayscale. Unfortunately, your question is currently too broad for StackOverflow.